# Java protect application from writing on disk

Tags: java, runtime

I have a problem with running a Java app (B) from my app (A). Code I use:

```
String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "java -Xmx16M -Xms2M -cp /root/ " + B + "> output.data"};
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
final Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);
Thread.sleep(1000);
proc.destroy();
```

I must stop app (B) from accessing my disk (write/read). How to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible by using a security manager [as described in the Java tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/security/tour2/index.html).